# Solving an upper triangular system in MATLAB using QR factorization

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I am writing a code to try and solve a triangular system derived from a QR factorization from first principals. This is the code i have so far:

```
function X = qr_solve(A,B)
[Q,R]=qr_givens(A);
t=0;
c=transpose(Q)*B;
n=length(A);
X(n,:)=c(n,:)/R(n,n);
for i=1:n-1
    for j=n-2:-1:0
        t=R(n-i,n-j)*X(n-j,:)+t;
        X(n-i,:)=(c(n-i,:)-t)/R(n-i,n-i);
    end
end
end
```

The function qr_givens works correctly. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code? It seems to be in the ball park of producing the right answer, but slightly off.

Comment: "slightly off" how slightly?

Comment: it starts populating the matrix correctly, and then some terms are in the wrong order and some terms are just wrong... Maybe I'm seeing patterns where there are none

Answer (score 1):

I think I've fixed it in the meantime!

```
function X = qr_solve(A,B)
%QR_SOLVE  Solve linear system using Givens QR factorization.
%  X = QR_SOLVE(A,B) solves the linear system
%  A*X = B using a QR factorization computed by QR_GIVENS.
%  Here, A is n-by-n and B and X are n-by-k.
[Q,R]=qr_givens(A);
t=0;
c=transpose(Q)*B;
n=length(A);
X(n,:)=c(n,:)/R(n,n);
for i=1:n-1
    for j=0:i    
    t=(R(n-i,n-j)*X(n-j,:))+t;
    end
        X(n-i,:)=(c(n-i,:)-t)/R(n-i,n-i);
end
end
```